# Como puedo modificar un array Object en nodejs usando map?

Tags: javascript, array, nodejs, jsonarray

Estoy realizando un proyecto usando el stack MERN, soy nuevo y en este momento tengo problemas con un controlador, especificamente intentando modificar un array. Al momento de recorrer el array, dentro hay unas consultas que sirven como validacion para poder modificar el campo estado basado en una condicion. El problema que tengo es que al finalizar el arreglo sigue siendo el mismo.

Dentro de los datos que se reciben esta el arreglo que es necesario validar llamado reservatios.

En el momento en que se empieza a recorrer el arreglo se hacen un par de consultas a base de datos para obtener unos valores que seran usados para saber si la cantidad de reservas que hay no supera las licencias que tiene una aplicacion. De cumplirse la condicion deberia cambiar el estado de esa reserva. Si lo veo en consola, uno por uno, me muestra el cambio pero al usarlo para responder el arreglo actualizado sigue siendo el mismo que llego.

```
reservationsCtrl.createReservationClass = async (req, res) => {
    const {users, apps_id, group_id } = req.body;
    let reservations = req.body.reservations;
    
    //saber licencias por app
    const lic = await db.Apps.findOne({
        attributes: ['licenses'],
        where: {
            id:{
                [Op.eq]: apps_id
            }
        }
    });
    const licenses = lic.licenses;

    reservations.map( async (reservation) => {
        
        const countIndividual = await db.Reservations.count({ 
            where: {
                [Op.and]: {
                    apps_id:{
                        [Op.eq]: apps_id
                    },
                    types_reservations_id: {
                        [Op.eq]: 1
                    },
                    [Op.or]: {
                        startDate: {
                            [Op.between]: [moment(reservation.startDate).subtract(5,'hours'), moment(reservation.endDate).subtract(5,'hours')]
                        },
                        endDate: {
                            [Op.between]: [moment(reservation.startDate).subtract(5,'hours'), moment(reservation.endDate).subtract(5,'hours')]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        //Consulta reservas clases y eventos
        const reservClass = await db.Reservations.findAll({
            where: {
                [Op.and]: {
                    apps_id:{
                        [Op.eq]: apps_id
                    },
                    types_reservations_id: {
                        [Op.in]: [2, 3]
                    },
                    [Op.or]: {
                        startDate: {
                            [Op.between]: [moment(reservation.startDate).subtract(5,'hours'), moment(reservation.endDate).subtract(5,'hours')]
                        },
                        endDate: {
                            [Op.between]: [moment(reservation.startDate).subtract(5,'hours'), moment(reservation.endDate).subtract(5,'hours')]
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            include: [
                {
                    model: db.Groups, 
                    as: 'Groups',
                    include: [
                        {
                            model: db.Users,
                            as: 'Users'
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        })
        let countUsers = 0;
       
        //Recorre reservas para contar los asistentes
        reservClass.forEach(reserv => {
            countUsers += reserv.Groups.Users.length;
        });

        //Total reservaciones (individual + Eventos/clases)
        let countReservs = countIndividual + countUsers;

        console.log("Licencias " + countReservs);
        if (countReservs >= licenses) {
            reservation.status = "inactive";
        }

        return [...reservations, reservation];
    });

    res.json(reservations); //Sigue igual que cuando entro
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema que tienes es que estás pensando que `map` actua directamente sobre tu objeto iterable, pero lo que hace el método [es devolver uno nuevo](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map), por lo tanto deberías de hacer algo cómo:

```
reservations = reservations.map( async (reservation) => {...
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder. Ya intente hacerlo de esa manera pero me devulve es un arreglo con los objetos vacios

Answer (score 0):

El problema que estaba teniendo radica en que al momento de usar map con async, al momento de la ejecucion lo que retorna no es el item, sino retorna un promesa por cada iteracion. Para esto es mejor usar la sentencia for para recorrer el arreglo e ir haciendo push del nuevo resultado.

[Aquí una mejor explicacíon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40140149/use-async-await-with-array-map/40140562#40140562)